# Normalizing in SQL with various character length

Tags: sql

I am trying to normalize a field in SQL.

Example:

```
HXDF469LDI

HXDF469801LDI
```

This is missing the preceding zeros before the 469.

It should be `HXDF000469LDI` or `HXDF000469801LDI`.

The preceding zeros can vary from 1-5 zeros missing. There should be six numbers after the HXDF but because some also contain an extension of 801, 802 and etc not sure how to do this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: not clear what you are looking for.. You wanted to get the column data in a unique way or you wanted to update the existing data?

Comment: I am using Teradata but I can also use SQL Server if need be.